# Salesforce: is it possible to develop a web application on top of Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Let me start with a bit of background: I'm helping a non-profit organization that would like to have a browser-based application that is backed by Salesforce, but has very specific requirements.

I see Salesforce has a REST API that we can call, so we can develop a standalone application to serve the web pages they want and use the REST API to call Salesforce when needed.

I'm wondering if there is a way to host a web application directly on Salesforce; this way we don't have to have a separate application server. Any recommendations or pointers to documentation/open source products is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create services that will allow your app to hit Salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of application, yes you can host it on salesforce using the Salesforce Sites feature, also you can develop and host your app on Heroku which is owned by salesforce and can sync data to and from salesforce using Heroku Connect, or you can build and host it on another service like AWS and connect via the REST API.  You just need to investigate and choose the option that best fits your use-case.  One thing to be aware of is that there are API limits (the number of calls you can make to salesforce in a rolling 24hr period).  Depending the the needs of the app be sure to see if those limits will be an issue.  Because if the app makes constant calls to salesforce that could be an issue.  But there are things you can do to get around that, like caching.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both Force.com Sites and Site.com features allow you to host webpages on the Force.com Platform.  The markup is stored in Visualforce Pages and can use Apex to access records in the Database.  I have migrated multiple websites (including our company's [www.mkpartners.com](http://www.mkpartners.com)) to Force.com using Force.com Sites.
One thing to keep in mind is that you are limited to 500,000 views per month and the rendering of a page with images that are also stored on the platform will incur a single view for the page and a single view for each image.  If you already have a very popular website, I wouldn't migrate.  If you're a small business or nonprofit, then it should be fine.
Another thing to keep in mind is that dynamic functionality based on records in the database will not work during maintenance windows.  There is the ability to upload a static version of your website to be rendered during these windows though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop a web application on top of Salesforce. Utilize Salesforce Lightning, which supports Lightning Web Components for modern UI. Leverage RESTful APIs for seamless data integration, or use Visualforce Pages for more traditional approaches. Consider Heroku for extensive applications within the Salesforce ecosystem. Tap into the active Salesforce developer community for resources and support. Assess your requirements and desired user experience to choose the most suitable approach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).